# skip retry mechanism and go straight to DLT

Tags: spring-kafka

We're my ErrorHandler logs and rethrows any exception that is not handled by the kafkalistener, so that the message is retried and eventually goes to DLT.

There are some failures which should not be retried, but should go straight to DLT e.g. json parsing errors.

Is there a way to skip retry mechanism for certain exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

See Spring Retry project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry and its `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy/ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy.java. That is what you can inject into the `RetryTemplate` for the `KafkaListenerContainer`.